# Connecting CA agile rally to fusion confluence

Tags: jira, rally, confluence, fusion

Is there any way/plugin/template to connect rally to confluence?

I've created a dashboard from some data from rally Iteration board which consists of Graphs and pie charts. Since that data is dynamic in nature, is there any way I can create a connector or embed plugin so that that dashboard gets updated automatically without explicitly updating it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed any apps written using appsdk 2 into a wiki:

https://docs.ca.com/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

Will that work for you?  What apps are you trying to embed?  There's not a way to embed an entire dashboard at once.